# Seaborn lineplot, different markers for different boolean values

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science, data-visualization

I have a dataframe that consists of 3 columns. Champion (categorical, holds string values), total damage done (numerical), win (holds Boolean values, True or False). I want to draw a line and I want its markers to be "o" if "win == True" and "x" if "win == False". I tried the code that I have attached here but it doesn't work.It gives `ValueError: Filled and line art markers cannot be mixed.`I tried to do it with hue or style but it changes the line style rather than marker. And I tried giving style my win column and I tried to make markers to follow from that, but that didn't work either. Can anyone help?
Thanks
[Only with `style` ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkjEZ.png)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

h = sns.lineplot(data=skyhill_all,x='champion',y='totalDamageDealt',style='win',markers=['o','x'])
h.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())


h.tick_params(which='both',width=2)
h.tick_params(which='major',length=8)
h.tick_params(which='minor',length=4)

h.set_ylabel('Total Damage Done')
h.set_xlabel('Played Champions')
h.set_yticks(np.arange(5000,75000,5000))

print(h)
```

Comment: When you add the hue feature and set it to use markers, markers will be given automatically. However, the marker will be reversed from what you want. This is the easiest way. If this is OK, I will answer. `sns.lineplot(data=skyhill_all,x='champion',y='totalDamageDealt', hue='win', style='win', markers=True)`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! It actually worked in terms of getting different markers. However, I only want one line instead of two, is there anyway to do that? [screenshot of last version](https://i.imgur.com/HE5UCUg.png)

Comment: What do you mean you want to make it one line?

Comment: [like this](https://i.imgur.com/kUuCJFv.png) but wins (true or false) need to be marked as 'x' or 'o' without having additional line like previous screenshot.

Comment: I recommend you to refer to this reference in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-marker-reference-py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to draw a line graph in matplotlib, then set the markers and colors in a scatter plot. The rest is setting the [seaborn style](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html#sphx-glr-gallery-style-sheets-style-sheets-reference-py). You can choose your own style in the future.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

skyhill_all = pd.DataFrame({'champion':list('ABCDEF'),
                   'totalDamageDealt':np.random.randint(100,10000,6),
                   'win': [True,False,False,True,True,False]})
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

m = ['o' if x == 1 else 'x' for x in skyhill_all['win']]
c = ['orange' if x == 1 else 'blue' for x in skyhill_all['win']]

ax.plot(skyhill_all['champion'], skyhill_all['totalDamageDealt'])
for i in range(len(skyhill_all)):
    ax.scatter(skyhill_all['champion'][i], skyhill_all['totalDamageDealt'][i], marker=m[i], color=c[i])
plt.show()
```

[image]